# How can I read multiple in json files in in folder structure?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read Training data for machine learning in json files, but they are stored in nested folders.

[image]

I'd like to know how can I read each json file into pandas frame.

Comment: You can use `os.listdir()` to get a list of filenames in a directory.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine there are three JSON files in a nested folder under data folder.

```
$ tree data
data
├── date1
│   ├── date2
│   │   └── file1_date2.json
│   └── file1.json
└── file1.json
```

glob2 module can be used to fetch the JSON files recursively.  glob returns a **list** of files.

```py
from glob2 import glob
jsonFiles = glob('data/**/*.json') #Can be used absolute or relative paths
print(jsonFiles)
```

```
['data/file1.json',  'data/date1/file1.json',  'data/date1/date2/file1_date2.json']
```

JSON files ban be loaded into dataframe by iterating thru the list **jsonFiles**.

```py
dfList = []
for jsonFile in jsonFiles:
    df = pd.read_json(jsonFile)
    dfList.append(df)
    
dfTrainingDF = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! It gave me all file paths of json files in the directory. But I keep getting this error "ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."

Comment: @JunYoungBang,  Are all JSON files follow the same structure (or schema)?  Based on the JSON string format, **orient** parameter needs to be adjusted.  Please check loading a single JSON file into a dataframe and see what is the format you should be using for reading the JSON file.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html will provide more info on reading JSON files.

Comment: "glob returns a list of files' _names_"